# SetThreadPriority and SetPriorityClass

Tags: windows, multithreading

I don't understand how to use `SetThreadPriority` and `SetPriorityClass` to lower and increase the priority of a Thread.

My understanding is that the `SetPriorityClass` selects the range of priorities available to a process and the `SetThreadPriority` sets the relative priority within the class.

For instance, what is the result of doing this for a thread :

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);

SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use GetThreadPriority() if you want to experiment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process priority class and the thread priority are building the `base priority` of a thread. See [Scheduling Priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find how the priorities are assembled. By looking at this list it becomes clear that your understanding is somewhat correct; within a certain priority class the `base priority` can have various values, determined by the `thread priority`.

The `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` value for `SetPriorityClass` and the `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END` value for `SetThreadPriority` are not supported on all Windows versions.

**PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN:**
*The system lowers the resource scheduling priorities of the process (and its threads) so that it can perform background work without significantly affecting activity in the foreground.*

**THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END:**
*End background processing mode. The system restores the resource scheduling priorities of the thread as they were before the thread entered background processing mode.*

The consequence of the scenario in question here is predictable: The `SetPriorityClass` will set the process with all of its threads into `background processing mode`. The following `SetThreadPriority` will only release the a thread from `background processing mode`. But all other possible threads of the process **will stay** in in background processing mode.

**Note:** Only the combination of `process priority class` **and** `thread priority` determines the `base priority`. Therefore neither a call to `GetThreadPriority` nor a call to `GetPriorityClass` will return the base priority. Only their combination releases the base priority which is described in the "Scheduling Priorities" link above. Unfortunately the new `background processing mode` values aren't yet included in the `base priority` list. But the name `base priority` tells what matters here: Based on the base priority (derived from process priority class and thread priority) the scheduler is allowed to dynamically adapt the scheduling priority. The background mode is just another way to `fine tune` the scheduling priority. Another way are [Priority Boosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The priority boost functionality exists for some time. The new access to `background processing mode` values for `SetThreadPriority` and `SetPriorityClass` opens the priority boost capability directly. In Windows XP this had to be done by a call to [SetProcessPriorityBoost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hey, I discovered that the THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END does not undo all the effects of PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN. See my answer.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: **THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END:** was taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): Do you state that `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` permanently limits the working set size to something rather small? Do you think it uses the [EmptyWorkingSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Have you double checked with [GetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? This would be very interesting! WinVersion?

Comment: I checked with `GetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx`: After entering background mode the max working set will be limited to 32MB and the `QUOTA_LIMITS_HARDWS_MAX_ENABLE` flag is also set. If I do not enter background mode then the max working set parameter is even some much smaller value: about 1.35MB, even after my huge memory allocations. But since `QUOTA_LIMITS_HARDWS_MAX_DISABLE` flag is set instead, the max working set does not have such/any effect on the real working set. I don't know whether `EmptyWorkingSet` is called, but as I understand, it anyway would not change working set parameters?

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: I think MSDN should add this to the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. How to make them do that?

Comment: @RolandPihlakas we have noticed the same thing. After PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN the max working set seems to be limited to 32MB. Which was bad since we are running a high CPU usage task. Our intention was that the user does not "feel it".

Answer (score 12):

One thing about `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` that I have observed but that has apparently not been documented, is that at least under Windows 7 it **empties the working set of the process PERMANENTLY**, no matter how the process accesses the memory - until the background mode ends.

For example, normally without `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`, when my machine has gigabytes of free memory, and the process needs to consume and constantly process gigabytes of memory, the **process working set** will be about equal to the allocation size. That is, the process gets all the memory it uses in its working set. Good. 

Now, with `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` the **working set** will be a few tens of megabytes! 

The bad result is, that this causes **constant page faults** and the computation runs much slower! The page faults are likely not to page file, but to Windows cache memory. But the page faults still slow the computation down significantly, while causing also the CPU to be consumed with meaningless load instead.

In conclusion, `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` is not suitable for low-priority background **work**. The work will be very time and **energy inefficient**.

`PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` is suitable only when the process really does not intend to do **anything consuming in the background**.

**In contrast**, `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` does not have such dreadful effects, even when the thread is the only thread in the process. 

Note also, that you need to turn off `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` for good, using only `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END`. It is not enough to call `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END` after `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`. 

So Arno is not quite correct with the claim that `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END` undoes the effects of `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` even for a single thread.

Additional note: `SetProcessPriorityBoost` with `bDisablePriorityBoost = TRUE` does not have any such effect on the working set.

Comment: Interesting. Did you re-try that a few years later on updated Win7 versions, or on Win10? I wonder if that was a result of some bugfix and disappeared after some time, or a real intended behavior kept today.

Comment: I just ran into this issue (https://crbug.com/1475179) after some bad Chrome installer behavior was reported on Windows 11. I then reproduced the working-set capping with a trivial test program on Windows 10. So, yeah. This (still undocumented behavior) has the potential to make your code run literally 100x slower. Madness.