# Preventing application from taking resources from other applications

Tags: c, windows, winapi, throttling

I have an application that does a lot of CPU and I/O heavy work. While this work is being done, it should not interfere with other applications.

For example, if another application is fully utilizing the disk my application is reading from, I want my application to throttle down it's disk access to very low speeds, so as not to interfere with the other applications. The same goes with CPU; if another application is encoding video, for example, I don't want to steal many cycles from it.

I've tried putting my threads in background mode, but I'm experiencing that these threads won't utilize unused resources. With no other applications running and almost no CPU or disk usage, an operation that takes 1 second on a normal priority thread takes up to 5 minutes on a background thread.

Does winapi provide anything to help me with this?

Below is a picture of my application's disk usage, while a background thread attempts to calculate the SHA1 hash of an 800 MB file. As you can see, it's barely utilizing my disk. On normal priority, it maintains 20 MB+ reads.

[image: disk usage]

**EDIT:** To clarify, by 'background thread,' I mean a thread with it's priority set to background mode, not a C# background thread.

```
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);
```

Answer (score 0):

For cpu utilization throttling:

- [SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219.aspx)
- [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277.aspx)

Just don't use THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN, anything that's below normal (has negative priority boost) should be fine. Windows schedules threads with higher priority to run first. Choose THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE if you wish even dynamic priority boosts to be almost always not enough to interfere with normal priority threads.

For information on IO priority, [click here](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7)

Comment: I am curious - why is `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` not to be used? What happens if it is used? According to my expriments, `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` is sometimes very unsuitable, but `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` looked entirely okay. See for more info about my findings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30509372/193017

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine – `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` is how you signal to the system that this thread is a background thread and that its I/O is to be treated as [low-priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg454515.aspx). You can achieve the same effect process-wide with `SetPriorityClass` and `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`. You can even control things at the file handle granularity with `SetFileInformationByHandle` and `FileIoPriorityHintInfo`.

So you are already doing what you intend to do. But you are finding that your task is not getting given any resource. That can only mean that there is at least one other thread running, and a higher than background priority, that is using resources.

Comment: I do have other threads doing things, but my disk is at very low utilization, and I have 12 threads on a 24 processor machine. It doesn't make sense to me that my background thread can't utilize the remaining resources. Overall, Process Explorer shows <5% utilization of everything.

Comment: I think there is another thread that is using the disk and the background thread never gets a look in.

Comment: Another thread may be using the disk, but with a very low throughput (i.e. 5 kb / second). Would this still prevent my background thread from using the remaining bandwidth?

Comment: I would not have thought so

Comment: I've added a screenshot; maybe you can see something that I don't.

Comment: See my answer to another question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30509372/193017 The `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` is not quite same as `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` even qualitatively. `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` empties the process working set **permanently**, no matter how the process uses its memory - until the background mode ends. No other related function does this, including `THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN`. See my answer for description of potentially bad effects and conclusions about where such call is appropriate.